# Workaround to Quantmod getDividends which apparently stopped working Jan 16, 2020

Tags: r, quantmod

My R program started failing Jan 16

```
 quantmod::getDividends('BBY')
gives:

Error in vapply(parse(text = fr[, 2]), eval, numeric(1)) : 
  values must be length 1,
 but FUN(X[[1]]) result is length 2
```

Comment: You may wrap with `tryCatch`

Comment: Apple stock is AAPL, not APPL.

Comment: sorry. I tried to make a simple example, but > getDividends('IBM')
Error in vapply(parse(text = fr[, 2]), eval, numeric(1)) : 
  values must be length 1,
 but FUN(X[[1]]) result is length 2

Answer (score 3):

Yahoo Finance changed the split ratio delimiter from "/" to ":".  For example, a 2-for-1 split was 1/2 but is now "2:1". This broke `getSplits()` and `getDividends()` (which called `getSplits()`).

This has been fixed in quantmod 0.4-16, which is on CRAN now. Windows binaries should be available over the next few days.